# How to create a circular progress bar that updates dynamically according to the value in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, animation, xamarin.forms, progress-bar

I want to create a circular progress bar according to the data value of a user which updates dynamically just like in this UI sample below:

[The circular bar sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ngyab.png)

It has some sort of animation that updates every time the user current value is changed.

I haven't found any solution so far... my question is, how can I achieve this result using Xamarin Forms, could anyone give me any insight?

Thanks!

Comment: https://xamaringuyshow.com/2020/07/11/xamarin-forms-progress-ring-with-counter/

Comment: https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/MyTripCountdown

Comment: https://dotjord.wordpress.com/2016/01/16/custom-made-xamarin-forms-radial-progress-control/

Comment: I found these links.  Can you please go through it?

Comment: Sure, thanks Anand!

Comment: @FernandoSchilipack Hi, if have solved this, can update it in answer when you have time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

~UPDATE~

I found one solution that solves my issue using this repo

https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/TemplateUI#progressbar

from Javier Juarez, there's a sample of a circular progress bar on it, also other controls as you like it.