# How do I show the percentage in the activity indicator at process time

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to show the percentage in the activity indicator at process time because the next page is taking a little time to load, so I used the activity indicator. Now I'm trying to show the percentage inside the activity indicator.

This is my current activity indicator without a percentage value.

[image]

This I'm trying to make activity indicator with percentage value.

[image]

Here I'm calling activity indicator

```
private async void ProductTypeButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    _Model.IsProcessing = true;
           
    await _Model.GetProductStatus();
    await Task.Delay(300);
    try
    {                
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ProductTypePage(_Model));              
    }
    finally
    {
        _Model.IsProcessing = false;
    }
}
```

Here I have created a loading indicator in a Xamarin shared project.
The percentage value is now appearing  `Txt.Text = String.Format("Progress: {0}%", progress);`, but the problem is that it is not resetting. That means that if I return to the main page and again go to the next page, that time percentage value does not begin with 1, but rather with when the last time stopped.

So far, this is how it looks.

[image]

```
public partial class LoadingIndicator : ContentView
{
        private int progress = 0;
        
        public LoadingIndicator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            IsVisible = true;
            IsVisible = false;
            
            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300.0), TimerElapsed);
        }

        bool TimerElapsed()
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                if (progress < 100)
                {
                    progress++;
                    Txt.Text = String.Format("Progress: {0}%", progress);
                }
            });
            //return true to keep timer reccurring         
            return true;
        }      
}
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+forms+circular+progress+bar+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define a custom circle progress bar for yourself.

And you can also find that there are many custom circle progress bar on the internet.

For example, you can check the following threads:

[C# custom control (circle progress bar) Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37379868/c-sharp-custom-control-circle-progress-bar-xamarin-forms),

[Oval progress bar using Xamarin Forms Shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72020550/oval-progress-bar-using-xamarin-forms-shapes),

[Xamarin Forms Progress Ring with Counter](https://xamaringuyshow.com/2020/07/11/xamarin-forms-progress-ring-with-counter/),

[How to create a circular progress bar that updates dynamically according to the value in Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63744375/how-to-create-a-circular-progress-bar-that-updates-dynamically-according-to-the).